# Error with cordova-universal-links-plugin: xmlPreferences.hasOwnProperty is not a function

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

I have a Cordova project using Vue and I'm using Cordova Android version 11. After adding the cordova-universal-links-plugin, I'm getting the following error during serve/build time: "xmlPreferences.hasOwnProperty is not a function".

Has anyone encountered this error before? Any suggestions on how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution!
The plugin is without any updates since 4 years ago. Searching for a forks of that plugin you will see some of them updated recently, with a solution for the problem, like this one:
https://github.com/e-imaxina/cordova-plugin-deeplinks/commit/04d7bf8db0c0ae0f26127a6e1eb43dce38a80784

You can use any of them or make your own fork of the plugin.

Hope it helps.

Comment: tanks @santiago, I found another plugin that works. https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-customurlscheme

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to use my fork of this plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-deeplinks-ios-build-fix

I fixed all issues for both android & iOS platforms.

Comment: Hi. Is there a reason I am seeing the following when preparing iOS?
`Cordova 7.0 detected - apply globSync()
require(...).globSync is not a function`
The error stops the building process :/